# Python quit unexpectedly which accessing cv2.VideoCapture(0)

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, pycharm

Please find below the simple script using openCV to capture the webcam video

```
import cv2,time


video=cv2.VideoCapture(0)

check,frame=video.read()
print(check)
print(frame)


time.sleep(3)
cv2.imshow("Capturing",frame)

cv2.waitKey(0)
video.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

I am running this on PyCharm using python3 . I am getting below issue 
[image]

Do you guys faced anything like this in MAC ? is there any workarounds ?

Answer (score 1):

Just solved this issue. There are 2 fails I encountered:

1. It just didnt work at all, like python just crashes unexpectedly, I solved that by uninstalling my opencv installation and installing full package by entering these commands:

```
pip3 uninstall opencv-python
pip3 install opencv-contrib-python
```

2. So once it was done, I faced my 2nd issue: When I ran the program through Sublime Text, it showed that it didn't have the permission to access the webcam, and I couldnt find a way to give it the permission, so I ran the program through terminal and it worked

Hope either of these solutions work :)

Answer (score -1):

It is related to permission issue to access the camera in MacOS. It is a known issue and was fixed now. Try updating the opencv. It was fixed in version 4 and also back ported to version 3.4.

Comment: thanks for the update . But i am already using 4.1.2 opencv version only >>> import cv2
>>> cv2.__version__
'4.1.2'
>>> .    My python version is 3.7.4

Comment: I have installed opencv using pip3 but I am seeing many documentation where its installed using brew . Is it worth to try out ?